# Typescript: Async * iterator closure not compiling

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Why does the following example not compile? Basically, the question is how to properly declare a async iterable closure.

```
class Test {
  async foo() {
    const c = async () => {
    };
    await c();
  }

  async * bar() {
    const c = async * () => {
    };
    yield * c();
  } 
}
```

The errors are:

```
...: error TS1109: Expression expected.
...: error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "out",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

If I change the example to the following, it works. I use a function instead of arrow syntax:

```
class Test {
  async foo() {
    const c = async () => {
    };
    await c();
  }

  async * bar() {
    const c = async function *() {
    };
    yield * c();
  } 
}
```

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: Could you please show the content of your tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)  `()=>{}` and regular function has a few differences which are in play here.

For example arrow function has no `this` binding.

Furthermore, documentation on generators clearly states that you have to use `function` syntax as it uses `this` for iteration.

This is why Async Generators are not going to support Arrow function

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for arrow-function using async-generators yet; i.e. `const c = async *()=> {};`.

> As with Generators, Async Generators can only be function
>   declarations, function expressions, or methods of classes or object
>   literals. **Arrow functions cannot be Async Generators.**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html